# How to find an entire sentences in a csv file and replace it with sentences from another file using bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

So I have two files file1 and file2:

```
file1:
my name is xyz.
my name is abc.
I am a doctor.
I am an engineer.
I like dogs.
I like cats.
```

I want to replace some of these sentences by shorter sentences. So I have created another file named file2.csv

```
file2.csv:
"my name is xyz.","name xyz"
"my name is abc.","name abc"
"I am a doctor.","doctor"
"I like dogs.","dogs"
```

I have used sed so far and if input all these lines individually in the sed command they work perfectly however the the contents of file1 and file2 may change according to my needs and i want a solution that doesn't need changing the script or the code.
Something like creating a 2 dimensional array and and then checking if the value in the first column of file2 exists in file1 and then replacing it with the corresponding entry in the second column of file2.csv

So after I run the shell script file 1 should look like:

```
name xyz.
name abc.
doctor.
I am an engineer.
dogs.
I like cats.
```

Note that the contents in file1 and file 2 can change or new entries can be added and hence using something like

```
sed -i 's/I like dogs/dogs/' file1.csv
```

is not feasible.

Comment: Why not creating a simple script to do the task?

Comment: yes I am trying to do that however I am stuck . I am finding it difficult to assign entire sentences to a variable or an array.When using awk it treats each word as a new column,that is undesirable,I want the entire sentence to be treated as one column and the next sentence as the second column.

Comment: Sounds like a homework question... [How do I ask homework questions on Stack Overflow](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+do+I+ask+homework+questions+on+Stack+Overflow). You are expected to make an effort.

Comment: Consider converting file 2 to a set of sed commands and then run that

Comment: Consider using TAB-separated files instead.  They are much simpler to parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using awk

```
awk -F'"(,")?' '
  NR==FNR { r[$2] = $3; next }
  { for (n in r) gsub(n, r[n]) } 1' file2.csv file1
```

- `-F'"(,")?'` is the field separator, matches a `"` or `","`, so that we don't need to remove double quotes from fields,
- `NR==FNR { r[$2] = $3; next }` populates an array with content of `file2.csv` using the full sentence as key and replacement string as value,
- `{ for (n in r) gsub(n, r[n]) } 1` searches for each full sentence in each input record and replaces it with the replacement string.

Comment: Hey thanks this is working perfectly..can you please explain me how this works exactly? I am new to shell scripting and still getting the hang of things thanks again

Comment: @AnujKulkarni, there's lots of good information on the awk tag info page: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info

Answer (score 2):

With bash and sed:

```
sed -f <(sed 's|","|/|; s|"|/|g; s|^|s|' file2.csv) file1
```

Output:

```
name xyz
name abc
doctor
I am an engineer.
dogs
I like cats.
```

The dot may be a problem because it is a special character in regex.

Comment: thanks but i get the following error: sed: file /dev/fd/63 line 1: unknown option to `s'

Comment: I had successfully tested it with bash 4.3.48 and GNU sed 4.2.2.

Comment: I am trying it on bash 4.4.23 and GNU sed 4.5 but getting that error.

Comment: You might want to add `s|/|\\/|g` to the sed script.

Answer (score 0):

A concise ruby script:

```
ruby -rcsv -e '
    sentences = CSV.read(ARGV.shift).to_h
    File.foreach(ARGV.shift, chomp: true) {|line| puts sentences[line] || line}
' file2.csv file1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl One liner.

```
$ cat file1
my name is xyz.
my name is abc.
I am a doctor.
I am an engineer.
I like dogs.
I like cats.

$ cat file2.csv
"my name is xyz.","name xyz"
"my name is abc.","name abc"
"I am a doctor.","doctor"
"I like dogs.","dogs"

$ perl -ne ' BEGIN {%kvp=map{chomp;s/\"//g;split "," } qx(cat file2.csv)} { chomp;print $kvp{$_}?"$kvp{$_}.\n":"$_\n"; } ' file1
name xyz.
name abc.
doctor.
I am an engineer.
dogs.
I like cats.

$
```